# How to use clang-format to check certain rules and return information about deviations?

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm currently evaluating `clang-format` against `cpplint` because I was hoping it is better maintained and can be combined with `clang-tidy`.

I could not find out some details yet which are very important to me. And most questions and answers I found are several years old - so I dare to ask again :)

**Is there a way** to make `clang-format` output information about what it's trying to reformat (together with a reason). I've found [clang-format-check](https://github.com/cloderic/clang_format_check) which reads the XML-output but there seem to be only locations.

**Is there a way** to only run certain checks which have been defined explicitly? I know you can just define a style which defines default values. But in some (most?) cases I don't want to let `clang-format` do *any* changes (but the ones I've defined explicitly).

**Is there a way** to make `clang-format` always apply rules which are usually only applied if some condition is met (like a too long line).
e.g. I want to reformat

```
foo(some_type const& arg1, some_other_type const& arg2, some<template> arg3);
```

to

```
foo(some_type const& arg1,
    some_other_type const& arg2,
    some<template> arg3);
```

even if my maximum column limit has not been reached yet..

Comment: Unfortunately, none of those things are currently supported by `clang-format`.